# Question on Reducing Multiple Trigger Logic (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

### Background:

I have a website (ASP.NET MVC) where users can write/edit/delete a "review".
Doing so needs to kick off a database trigger to update some global statistics on the system.

### Database Tables:

- Review (parent)
- MetaData1 (Review 1 - 0..1 MetaData1)
- MetaData2 (Review 1 - 0..1 MetaData2)
- MetaData3 (Review 1 - 0..* MetaData3)

So **Review** is the main table (ReviewId - identity), and the other's are meta data.

### The problem:

I have a stored procedure which performs the calculations, which needs to be called whenever a review is created/edited/deleted.

At the moment, i have a trigger which calls the SP on *all* tables (4 identical triggers). But this results in the stored procedure being executed possibly 4 times when it only needs to be done once.

I can't just put it on Review only, because if a user edits metadata for a review, Review table will not be touched and hence the trigger will not fire.

I need a way of saying "watch all of these tables for activity, when a record is created/edited/deleted, fire off this procedure once."

Any tips/suggestions/ideas?

FYI - i'm using Entity Framework 4 for the CRUD operations, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop triggers on 3 MetaDataX tables. After saving metadata records, really change something ("last edited" time would be a good candidate) in the Review table.

You may want to write some proxy methods to implement the above logic in Review mapped class to manipulate the metadata objects (and do not use MetaDataX mapped objects directly).

Comment: "After saving metadata records, really change something" - where/how - you mean a trigger on the meta data tables? Wouldn't this still cause the procedure to be executed twice? (once on review touch, then again when touched by metadata update)? Still better than 4 i guess.

Comment: When you insert/update/delete metadata records for a review, "touch" the parent record in the Review table only once.

Comment: I understand what your saying, but where does this "touch" happen? What performs the touching? (lol, this is sounding like a porn script)

Comment: You gave me an idea - i have a method called "UpdateReview" in my application which always get's called regardless of what part of the review is touched. Here i already touch the last modified, so the Review record will always be touched - therefore i only need the trigger on Review table as you say. Thanks for putting me on the right track - accepted!

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the entity framework and triggers.  Create a stored procedure that updates four tables, and call that from your web page.

Comment: "Get rid of entity framework"? So your telling me to throw away my entire DAL because of a trigger scenario? No way. I've found a solution based on @Dennis P. Nikolaenko's answer.